# How to use a host and port for a SQL Server connection

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was given a host and a port to connect to a database using SQL Server Management studio. I usually create a new connection using the server name which I do not have this time. I tried to write "host, port" in the box of the server name but the connection failed. Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: my error says: "A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. Error 10054"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to write "host, port" in the box of the server name but the connection failed.

That's the correct format.  So you're on to network troubleshooting.  eg in powershell

```
 Test-NetConnection -ComputerName [host] -Port [port]
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I do not understand what you are referring to. What should I do exactly?

Comment: Start powershell.  Run the `test-netconnection` command substituting your values for [host] and [port].

Comment: ok now I try. In the meantime, my error says: "A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. Error 10054"

Comment: Ok I launched the test. Now what? TcpTestSucceeded: True

Comment: Now check the SQL Server error log on the server, read  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dataaccesstechnologies/an-error-occurred-during-the-pre-login-handshake-dbnetlibconnectionopen-secdoclienthandshake-ssl-security-error-when-connecting-to-sql-server A common cause for this error is that the server is configured to require secure connections, and the client and server don't have an enabled SCHANNEL protocol in common.

Comment: If I am not wrong it says that I have to set Enabled equal to 1 in the following path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0 \Server but actually after Protocols I do not have any subfolder, TLS 1.0 does not exist

Comment: Unfortunately you need to check the Server's SQL Error Log for other possible causes, and check the SCHANNEL configuration on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I use the next format to connect by SSMS:

```
tcp:YOUR_IP_ADDRESS\INSTANCE_NAME, PORT_NUMBER
```

For example, my home connection lools like this:

```
tcp:localhost\MSSQLSERVER, 1433
```

Or this:

```
tcp:localhost, 1433
```

Comment: Don't use both the instance name and the port.  It's either one or the other.